# Installing Mesa 10 on Debian

Tags: opengl, mesa

So, here's my problem - I want to complete [these](http://www.arcsynthsis.org/gltut) tutorials on a laptop with an HD4000 integrated graphics processor running Kali *nix. The trouble is that the edition of Mesa 3D installed is only version 8 or so, and therefore will only run an implementation of OpenGL which is too old - the tutorial requires OpenGL version 3.3 or higher. However, the recent release of Mesa 10 has made this possible by providing support for OpenGL 3.3!!

So all I want to do is install Mesa 10 on my system, so I can complete these tutorials. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589728/29469320) answer, but it seems to be for Ubuntu only. I tried running the suggested

```
1.) Add the PPA Repository
  $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
2.) Update sources
  $ sudo apt-get update
3.) Dist-upgrade (rebuilds many packages)
  $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
4.) Reboot!
In your code make sure you request a Opengl 3.3 context!
```

but after 2). I got the errors

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

I also downloaded the tar.gz Mesa 10 file from the website directly, and configure it after running

```
sudo apt-get build-dep mesa
```

Though this produced the error;

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libdrm_radeon >= 2.4.46) were not met:

Requested 'libdrm_radeon >= 2.4.46' but version of libdrm_radeon is 2.4.40
```

Comment: How did you invoke `configure`?

Comment: "./configure --with-dri-drivers=i965" though I tried just "./configure", the only apparent difference being that it results in errors of different libdrm files missing or out of date, namely "libdrm_radeon", and "libdrm_nouveau" respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `--with-gallium-drivers=""` to your `configure` invocation:

```
./configure --with-dri-drivers=i965 --with-gallium-drivers=""
```

You'll probably have to build a newer version (`>= 2.4.49`) of [`libdrm-intel`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/drm/tag/?id=libdrm-2.4.49) than Wheezy ships (`2.4.40`) though.

Answer (score 1):

You shoudn't try add ubuntu repositories to a debian system.

Also, hw accelerated mesa requires you to update dri/drm libraries and associated kernel modules.That libdrm_radeon might just be the beginning. By manually updating all that, you will end up having a lot of non-distro stuff. And it won't be fun to compile and update all that (not even mentioning dist-upgrades).

As an alternative, you could try to install the fglrx proprietary driver (for your GPU, you will need the "legacy" version). Have a look at [this debian wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary) for the recommended way to install this on debian.

Comment: The fglrx proprietary driver seems to be for ATI graphics chips - I'm using the intel HD graphics 4000 chip that's built into the CPU. Do you have any idea how I can find support for that?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought you meant radeon HD 4000. Especially as you meantioned that radeon lib. So my answer is besides the point. For intel on linux, there are only the open source drivers as part of the mesa3d project. IIRC you can disable unneeded drivers (like radeon) when building mese. But I fear that you might end up with the same problem regadring intel libs...

Comment: It's when I ./configure inside the Mesa 10 folder with the attribute "--with-dri-drivers=i965" that produces the error referencing radeon. If I just ./configure without specifying the driver it produces an error referencing libdrm_nouveau.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this guide](http://x.debian.net/howto/build-mesa.html). It shows you how to build Mesa from git on a Debian system.