# Opengl 3 on Ubuntu 12.04 running in VmWare

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, vmware, mesa

The question is simple: is there a way to get OpenGL 3+ support on Ubuntu 12.04 launched on VmWare Fusion?

Now I installed mesa project environment which gives me this output of glxinfo | grep -i opengl:

```
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.4
```

I know there is a mesa version 10 which should bring support of OpenGL 3+, how do I install it on Ubuntu 12.04? Suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565680/how-to-enable-opengl-3-3-using-mesa-10-1-on-ubuntu) topic did not help, I still get mesa 8.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ubuntu (I do not even know if that is a new version number), but I do know it is derived from Debian... so I'd consider `apt-cache search mesa`. Maybe there is a separate package for Mesa 10?

Comment: I found the solution for this and I don't know how to move this question to SuperUser. Please move it if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way for me was to move to ubuntu 14.04LTS which have Mesa 10 available out-of-the-box.

Comment: Could you provide more information? What further steps did you have to do to get OpenGL 3 support?

Comment: Hi Nick, sorry I missed your comment. Back then I just installed oibaf graphic drivers: https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers and it just worked. But now I am not so sure, as they now tell that the best supported version for their PPA is 15.10. So, ubuntu 14.04 with latest updates does not support OpenGL 3.0 with software drivers?