# OpenGL 3.3 on an Intel Graphics under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, intel

I'm running that configuration :

Ubuntu 12.04

Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller

`glxinfo` give me that parameters:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Desktop 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:
```

I did

```
1.) Add the PPA Repository
  $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
2.) Update sources
  $ sudo apt-get update
3.) Dist-upgrade (rebuilds many packages)
  $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
4.) Reboot!
```

I got mesa 10,but OpenGL is still 3.0.I found some people say [Intel Graphics doesn't support OpenGL 3.3 yet.](https://askubuntu.com/a/256798/104412) but some say  [in the last official release of Mesa (10.0), GL 3.3 only works on Intel hardware.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21567167/1278112)
but some people [work out.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589728/1278112)

Does Ubuntu 12.04 support OpenGL 3.3?

Does Intel Graphic support it?

What should I do to enable GL3.3

Comment: Depends on what Intel HD model you have.
For example, I have an Intel HD 3000, and it supports up to OpenGL 3.1.

Comment: @Sir.Tiddlesworth  where to find the reference whether it support?

Comment: Open the terminal, and enter this: 'lspci | grep VGA'

It should tell you your graphics card model.

Comment: It's Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core,I already told in the question.But where to find if it support GL3.3 @Sir.Tiddlesworth

Comment: Just did a bit of research, and your Intel HD card is the P4000, so it should support OpenGL 3.3 on Linux. From the looks of it, you have taken the same steps others have taken to get it working on older versions of Ubuntu.

If you are able to update, a new version of Ubuntu might be your best bet.

Comment: recompiling latest mesa is enough...

Comment: @j-p I searched there are a lot of mesa related folder in my computer.Recompile which one?Where is the latest mesa?

Comment: http://www.mesa3d.org/ Download the latest version from here. The ones on your computer / in apt are likely out of date.