# opengl3.0 in ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, opengl-3

is it possible to have opengl|Es 3.0 or above with these system configuration:

Dell Inspiron 1464

```
processor - Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 350 @ 2.27GHz × 4 
graphics - Intel® Ironlake Mobile
os Type - 64 bit
```

when i run glxinfo i have output as:

```
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
```

i did also use launchpad to get opengl 3.0

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

but got this response from glxinfo:

```
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
```

i do find on some places that intel ironlake mobile graphics do not support opengl 3.0 fully, as i have also intall all the intel graphics drives in my other OS windows7 to get opengl 3.0 but it still says 2.1 only, while it showing some of the features of 3.0 and 3.1 but not fully.
    https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/281262
the image in this link shows the exact case of mine in Windows 7.(i could not able to post the image but you'll surely get the proper picture of the problem from the link's image)

Mesa utils also says that it supports opengl 3.0 from 8.0 but totally depends on the system graphical support.

i needs opengl 3.0 very badly, can some one please give any idea regarding this.

i did see

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123895/opengl-glsl-3-3-on-an-hd-graphics-4000-under-ubuntu-12-04

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565680/how-to-enable-opengl-3-3-using-mesa-10-1-on-ubuntu
```

and many other links like these but could not get any solution.

i have already tried AMD catalyst drivers (15.7, 14.12, 12.1, 13.1)but not supported i.e they were all installed `fglrx` but when i ran `aticonfig` or `amdconfig` they says `no supported adapters`, and they are giving same opengl 2.1 response.

lspci -v | grep VGA result:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 12) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

lspci -v result:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0434
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 12) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0434
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 1800 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0434
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    Memory at f0605800 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0434
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f0606000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0434
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at f0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: c0000000-c01fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0200000-00000000c03fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: c0400000-c08fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0700000-00000000f07fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0434
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f0606400 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0434
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0434
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
    I/O ports at 1818 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 180c [size=4]
    I/O ports at 1810 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 1808 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 1820 [size=32]
    Memory at f0605000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0434
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    Memory at f0606800 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 1840 [size=32]

00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0434
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at f0604000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel ips

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0434
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at f0710000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f0700000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at c0400000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
```

lspci -nnk result:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0044] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0434]
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0434]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller [8086:3b64] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0434]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b3c] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0434]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio [8086:3b56] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0434]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:3b42] (rev 06)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 [8086:3b4c] (rev 06)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b34] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0434]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller [8086:3b09] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0434]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:3b29] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0434]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller [8086:3b30] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0434]
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem [8086:3b32] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0434]
    Kernel driver in use: intel ips
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0434]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
ff:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c62] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:8086]
ff:00.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder [8086:2d01] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:8086]
ff:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 [8086:2d10] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:8086]
ff:02.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 [8086:2d11] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:8086]
ff:02.2 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved [8086:2d12] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:8086]
ff:02.3 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved [8086:2d13] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:8086]
```

Comment: what about `lspci -v` output ?

Comment: ok, looks like i915 with id 0046. check with `lspci  -nnk` https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81510/Mobile-Intel-915GM-GMS-910GML-Express-Chipset-Family

Comment: And, in general https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/13815/Intel-Graphics-Drivers-for-Linux

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux yes it's i915.

Comment: the download link shows many options, can you please varify which one will be suitable, because i have a linux kernal of 3.16 and latest one shows 4.x.
also find a link related to 2013 says http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM2MTA

Comment: Looks like OpenGL 2.1 is the best you could get from Intel

Answer (score 0):

Well i have tried these unsuccessful options..

1. installs almost all intel and AMD drives.
2. upgrade to ubuntu 14.10 and install intel driver installation deb as it
   supports only ubuntu 14.10 and a fedora version.
3. installs propriatery drivers(iobaf) many times , but as i says 15.04 i have 
   also upgrade to ubuntu 15.04 and tried it again, no success.

My processor is ironalake Arrandale, 2.26 GHz Core i3 350 M.
Intel HD Graphics.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units

http://ark.intel.com/products/43529/Intel-Core-i3-350M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_26-GHz

I don't think that it's possible to have Opengl 3.0 with these configuration, either in windows or in linux.
If someone finds any solution regarding that then kindly share it here, it would be very helpful.
for now i am using ubuntu 15.04 as it goes good with my AndroidStudio with NDk support, and i am using my Android Device to have opengl 3.0 support as my system can't give it to Genymotion which i wanted to run for Opengl 3.0 support.