# QT/ C++/ OpenGL/ Ubuntu: Update OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, opengl

So... On a QT project using OpenGL, and all my shaders run into this problem:

"GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, and 3.00 ES"

(I am trying to use #version 330)

This is in a virtual machine (Oracle) running ubuntu 17.10, with OpenGL version string: 3.0, Mesa 17.2.2
Is it possible to update the version of OpenGL in this setup? Do I have to change anything on the virtual machine setup? Or am I completely off mark and the problem is something else entirely?

@Edit:
Thank you! I read that question and its answers... And I still get the same error :/
I am using "#version 330 core" now, and I double checked the info o my Mesa version, and it should go up to 3.3 core...
This same code was compiled in a different version of Linux (I am sorry, I don't remember what version and don't have access to it, but I believe it was also on core context. Or is there a different driver I can install to get compatibility context?) I wonder, is there is anything else I need to install or update on the system for the core context to work?
(Sorry, I am so confused on how to get this to work :o)

Comment: There is no mesa which supports GL 3.3 in a non-core profile, so an update would be completely useless. The correct solution is to use a core profile.

Comment: See this question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565680/how-to-enable-opengl-3-3-using-mesa-10-1-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thank you! I read that question and its answers... And I still get the same error :/

Comment: just writing `#version 330` into your shaders isn't going to change the GL context the application has created. You need to adjust the whole context creation.